# Как написать запрос, чтобы получился такой результат?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

[image: Таблицы с данными]

Есть таблица с успеваемостью студентов. Какой запрос надо написать к базе с большим количеством записей, чтобы в результате были записи со студентами у которых есть хотя бы одна оценка равная 2? То есть в результате нужны записи где есть оценка 2, но и другие записи этих же студентов тоже должны быть.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.
Все в рамках вопроса как текст, без картинок.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать условие IN

```
select * from `table` where (`table`.`student`) IN (select `table`.`student` from `table` where `table`.`grade` = 2)
```

В условии мы выбираем все записи из table, у которых записи в столбце table.student присутствуют в столбце, который мы запрашиваем после условия IN.